# Selenium Webdriver - Java - How to click checkbox based on product

Tags: java, selenium, checkbox

I would like to click checkbox based on link text. There are several checkbox in the page so using the link text I wanted to find value of the checkbox so that I can click on the checkbox

Note # All values are dynamically generated

Can you please help correct the code to include this logic. Thanks

```
   driver.get(new URI(driver.getCurrentUrl()).resolve("/admin/lms/tag").toString());
   String tag_name = sheet1.getRow(j).getCell(0).getStringCellValue();
   driver.findElement(By.linkText(tag_name)).click();
   WaituntilElementpresent.isExist();
   String tag_value = sheet1.getRow(j).getCell(1).getStringCellValue();
   driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a[href*='"+tag_value+"']")).click();
   WaituntilElementpresent.isExist();
   String product = sheet1.getRow(j).getCell(2).getStringCellValue();
   WaituntilElementpresent.isExist();
   driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[name='products[]'][value='11']")).click();
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/mOBY2.png

Comment: Please post the HTML as text properly formatted in your question instead of as an image. Also, please take a minute to fix the indent of your code so that it's more easily readable.

Comment: Updated my question per your request

Answer (score 1):

You could use an xpath like this:

```
//tr[.//*[text()='OPIOIDMORTEPID']]//input
```

this means to locate the `td` that has this exact text and find the `input` from it.
If you want to use partial text then:

```
//tr[.//*[contains(text(), 'MORTEPID')]]//input
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with the following strategy:

1. find the link by using the link text
2. get the parent `tr` element
3. from there, find the `input` element of the checkbox
4. click on the checkbox

This can be done as follows:

```
WebElement link = driver.findElement(By.linkText("OPIOIDMORTEPID"));
WebElement trElement = link.findElement(By.xpath("../.."));
WebElement checkboxElement = trElement.findElement(By.tagName("input"));

checkboxElement.click();
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this out:

1. Get a list of checkbox WebElements that have a common locator i.e. a common class name or tag name (this WebElement would have to have the text or be a parent of the element that has the text).

   ```
   List<WebElement> checkBoxElements = webDriver.findElements(By.cssSelector("checkbox"));
   ```
2. Iterate through the list and check if the WebElement has the text you are looking for. If it does, click it!

   ```
   for (WebElement e : checkBoxElements) {
       if (e.getText().contains("Something dynamic")) {
           e.click();
       }
   }
   ```
3. Be happy that this works.

Answer (score 0):

I would write this section as a function so that it's reusable.

```
public static void selectByProductName(String value)
{
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//tr[//a[text()='" + value + "']]/td/input")).click();
}
```

and then call it like

```
selectByProductName("OPIOIDMORTEID");
```

Comment: Hi Jeff, I tried with above code but it doesn't locate the product and click on the checkbox. Appreciate your assistance!!